# AngularJS cloned element in directive (with no controller) calls function from controller twice

Tags: angularjs, directive

I wrote a directive to fix the header of the table to top on scroll. It works fine. Table is also sortable. When user clicks to the header of a column, list is sorting by that column and when user clicks active column, sorting is reversed. Everything works as I expected. But when I clicked to fixed header, sort function gets called twice (you can see it in the console).

I can't find the source of the problem and how to solve it. Here's my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EMmvEvLt2hV6PDXpWOzp?p=preview). Thanks in advance for any help...

Btw, if I remove the compiling codes (

```
var linkFn = $compile(fixedHeader);
linkFn(scope);
```

), it works fine. But then ng-class does not apply, because i think it can not access to the controller variables.

**Edit:**

I've updated the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EMmvEvLt2hV6PDXpWOzp?p=preview) to show my problem with ng-class when I delete compiling codes.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that when you do this

```
 fixedHeader = header.clone(true).addClass("header-fixed").width(header.width());
```

and then doing

```
  var linkFn = $compile(fixedHeader);
  linkFn(scope);
```

you are not only copying the html, but also the bindings, so you don't need to compile it and linked again but since you are doing it, your events get executed twice because they are linked twice. so you can go ahead and remove the $compile or assign the header.html() content to your fixed header and compile it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found out that but not a solution unfortunately. Check my edit...

Comment: what am i supposed to see here? looks the same to me with and w/o compiling

Comment: ng-class doesn't apply to fixedHeader without compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Give angular.copy() a try:

```
 fixedHeader = angular.copy(header).addClass("header-fixed").width(header.width());
```